# Load data file pyomo

Tags: python-3.x, upload, pyomo

How can I load a data file of a model to run in pyomo , I want to run a specific model but I do not know in which directory I should save the `file.dat` so that it can be run by the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to have your data file in the same directory as the .py file containing your model. Please see the Pyomo online documentation for more details (http://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data/index.html)